# issues running Sidekick project on iPhone

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am learning NativeScript Vue and trying to transition from the online Play to Sidekick.  I have gone thru the documentation:

1. [Code Signing](https://docs.nativescript.org/sidekick/user-guide/code-signing/code-signing-for-ios/create-development-provisioning)
2. [Run App on Device](https://docs.nativescript.org/sidekick/user-guide/run-app/run-app-on-device)

Here are the steps I have done thus far:

1. Created a paid Apple Developer account (don't really intend on selling on the app store but you never know, right?)
2. Created a Development Certificate
3. Downloaded the development certificate (ios_development.cer) to ~/Downloads
4. Created a Development Provisioning Profile
5. Downloaded the provisioning profile (xxx.mobileprovision) to ~/Downloads
6. Updated to the latest version of NativeScript as per these [instructions](https://docs.nativescript.org/releases/upgrade-instructions)
7. Opened my downloaded Play project in NativeScript Sidekick
8. Connected my iPhone 8+ to my Macbook Pro
9. In the Connected Devices section, updated the Provisioning and Certificates with the downloaded profile but *I could not add the certificate generated above, but only with one created when I made my Apple Developer account*.
10. If I do a local build then I get:

> [18-10-25 07:15:27.576] Build failed. ENOENT: no such file or
>   directory, scandir '/Users/xxx/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning
>   Profiles/'

Selected my attached iPhone and clicked "Run on Device" to get the error:

> [18-10-25 07:01:26.078] Error detected during LiveSync on
>   716bd55f99272ba6acb7af3dfb3ce5d079a40ba5 for
>   /Users/xxx/projects/private/xxx. Error: ENOENT: no such file or
>   directory, scandir '/Users/xxx/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning
>   Profiles/'

So this seems like a certificate/provisioning issue but I am uncertain what I am doing wrong.  I do see that my Sidekick General settings "Application Identifier" has a warning ("This value should match the App ID of your iOS provisioning profile) but I do not see how to fix that in either Sidekick or Apple Developer and am not sure that is the root of these problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you might have forgot to add your device id to developer portal and include same in provisional profile while creating.

Comment: is it best to just delete my developer profile in the Apple Developer, then add my device and recreate profiles and certificates?

Comment: You don't have to recreate the certificates. Just add the device id in the identifiers section and you must have option to edit your provisional profile where you should see your device id being listed with a checkmark, you just have to check them and download the updated one.